# How would a qualified immunity defense be defeated in the Cantu San-Antonio shooting?

Tags: texas, civil-rights, qualified-immunity

Given the video shown in the recent Cantu San-Antonio shooting:

https://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2022/10/08/san-antonio-police-shooting-teen-vpx.cnn

How would the teenager's attorney overcome / nullify a [Qualified Immunity Defense](https://ij.org/issues/project-on-immunity-and-accountability/frequently-asked-questions-about-ending-qualified-immunity/)?  Are there any observations of the video that would nullify qualified immunity?

Comment: There are many, in fact, 42 U.S. Code § 1983 is a whole area of law for itself. Please cut down to size.

Comment: The question would be improved by a description of the incident. Links rot and the posts are intended to be useful for future users of the site.

Answer (score 2):

> A San Antonio Police Department officer has been fired after shooting
> a 17-year-old boy who was eating a meal in a McDonald’s parking lot,
> the department said. The teen was charged with evading detention in a
> vehicle and assaulting the officer. All charges have been dropped.

To prevail on a 42 U.S.C. § 1983 claim and defeat the qualified immunity defense in this context, a plaintiff must show that the law enforcement officer intentionally violated a well-established constitutional right.

To use force lawfully to prevent an escape of a suspected criminal, under the Fourth Amendment of the U.S. Constitution (as incorporated against U.S. states under the due process clause of the 14th Amendment to the U.S. Constitution), a police officer may use deadly force to prevent the escape of a fleeing suspect (whose status as a suspect is supported by probable cause) only if the officer has a good-faith belief that the suspect poses a significant threat of death or serious physical injury to the officer or others. *Tennessee v. Garner*, [471 U.S. 1](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/471/1/) (1985).

In this case, the officer may have had a reasonable suspicion (the car looked similar to one he had been on the lookout for in connection with a car theft case although it was not actually the same one), although not probable cause (since there are many cars of the same color, make, and model of almost any type on the road at any one time), to believe that the car in question was stolen by a person who was not armed other than having the car. This probably doesn't meat the *Garner* test for constitutionality.

Alternatively, the use of force could be justified for self-defense or in the defense of others, if the car's hypothetical use as a weapon gave the officer probable cause to believe a suspect posed an imminent threat of serious bodily harm to the officer or others which the use of deadly force could prevent (as discussed in dicta in *Garner*).

In this case, the question of whether the officer was actually in imminent risk of serious harm, when the officer, in fact, never even came into contact with the car and was off to the side of it, would also be weak.

Shooting someone without either justification ought to overcome the qualified immunity defense.

A full qualified immunity legal analysis would cited also to binding precedents from the U.S. Court of Appeals for the 5th Circuit restating these U.S. Supreme Court enunciated constitutional right in circumstances as factually similar to this case as possible, to underline the fact that these constitutional rights are "well-established". Likewise, the plaintiff's lawyer would have to allege facts (which could be supported with affidavit testimony not contradicted by the videotaped evidence) that would support the arguments set forth above.

Comment: Good to hear from you: a thoughtful well-articulated response.   If we can surmise that Cantu was not fleeing, based on the **dropped charges:** "evading detention in a vehicle and assaulting the officer": perhaps paragraph is not applicable?  i.e.  not fleeing (evading) therefore no justification of deadly-force?

Comment: @gatorback There is potentially a lot of politics at play in the decision to drop the charges.  It doesn't mean the officer can't try to show Cantu _was_ fleeing in his (the officer's) defence.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I agree. The fact that law enforcement officials learned that the boy shot was not actually engaged in criminal activity at the time that the officers started yelling at him, and that it would not be possible to show beyond a reasonable doubt that he didn't accidentally remove his foot from the brake because he was being confronted by a police officer, which would justify dropping the charges, doesn't impact the officer's perception of the situation which is the critical factual inquiry in a qualified immunity analysis.